# Как подключиться к удаленному серверу?

Tags: python, сервер

Вчера писал клиент-серверное приложение в локальной сети, все работает, вот код:
Server.py:

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 2020
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
data = conn.recv(1000000)
print ('client is at', addr , data)
conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Client.py

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 2020
s.connect((host, port))
s.send('hello!'.encode())  
data = s.recv(1000000) 
print ('received', data, len(data), 'bytes')
s.close()
```

А сегодня я снял на месяц удаленный сервер windows, затем я установил на него python и в IDLE запустил код Server.py.
Я не понимаю какое мне Ip надо указывать в "host" в файле Server.py и какое мне нужно указывать в Client.py, когда я указываю в клиенты хост(или айпи) самого компьютера я подключаюсь к самому компьютеру, но не подключаюсь к самому серверу на питоне, помогите как это реализовать? Я так понимаю что в клиенте мне каким то образом нужно делать подключение вначале к удаленному компьютеру а затем уже к серверу питон? я правда не понимаю(( помогите

P.S
вот немного информации про удаленный компьютер:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Порт VNC: 5956

Помогите пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

P.S
я уже пробовал ставить хост 0.0.0.0

Comment: У сервера хост должен быть `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @gil9red у сервера который на питоне всмысле?

Comment: @gil9red неа( не работает все равно(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В скрипте сервера хост должен быть `0.0.0.0`. В скрипте клиента укажите адрес машины `94.103.88.125`.

Comment: неа не работает(( а порт я указываю 5856? просто это порт для VNC это он же для подключение получается или нет?

Comment: port = 2020 у вас же вы коде написанно

Comment: не, это я когда в локалке делал я сам такой порт придумал, а щас же на удаленный комп, на сайте сервера написано про какой то VNC port = 5856

Comment: причем тут vnc? какой порт придумал - там и пользуйся

Comment: Тоесть в скрипте сервера я указываю свой придуманный код,  и в скрипте клиента я тоже указываю свой придуманный код, но в скрипте клиента порт я указываю VNC или опять же придуманный? просто если придуманный то я же изначально наверное к самому компу не смогу подключиться?

Comment: Я вроде все способы перепробовал не получается(((

Comment: помоги плз не понимаю что не так

Comment: фаервол настроил на винде?

Comment: а что это? я не знаю((

Comment: напиши в вопросе что пробовал. кнопка править снизу

Comment: зачем ставить виндовс - если не умеете им пользоваться...

Comment: слушай там был выбор винда или линукс,лучше уж винду поставить(

Comment: а что мне надо в вопрос добавить? способы которые я попробовал?

Comment: у меня еще вопрос, я в клиенте почему то в хосте не могу цифры набирать, тоесть я не могу поставить в нем хост компа(94.103.88.125) в нем у меня только адреса получалось вводить(

Comment: @leocoolguy0, а как там с браундмаузером (firewall)? Вводить в клиенте, в смысле в скрипте? Там хост только как ip может быть, это же сокеты...

Comment: в браунмаузере я указал чтобы ничего не блокировал, а вот в чем проблема:           host = '94.103.88.125' когда я вот так в питоне ввожу мне пишет ошибку:                            s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused, ну вот странно я когда туда ссылку на сайт ввожу в хост все норм а когда пытаюсь цифры вот так ввести ловлю ошибку((

Comment: линукс проще в настройке.
да, способы которые Вы пробовали.

Comment: браунмаузер не настроен

Comment: @eri,@gil9red все у меня получилось! я еще поднастроил браундмаузер и с портом поигрался и все заработало, спасибо!)